# Inactivate AWS EKS master?

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kops

is there a way to 'inactivate' an EKS cluster? I'm aware that the worker can be suspended (EC2) but it would be nice to also suspend the EKS master since we will only use the cluster for dev/test and it would be great to be able to switch it off when not needed (to safe cost of 0.20 $ / hour). 
There is the alternative to use kops (which would create a master node as EC2 instance) but maybe there is a way with EKS.

cheers

Comment: not yet, simplest way is to throw everything in a script/CICD or use simple eksctl to rebuild the cluster every morning

Answer (score 0):

Currently, EKS master nodes cannot be scaled down to 0. There is an open request for the same. https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/318